# nested mysqli_query gives no results back

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

In this code below I need to echo the result of the subquery.
When I echo `$row['email'].'<br>';` the echo works okay and I get all the emails.

Problem is that this:

```
$resultsub.echo $rowb["email"];
```

is empty

Question: what do I do wrong in the subquery: $resultsub?

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM wp_mm_email_bounces");

if ($result) {
// output data of each row
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result ) )
        {
            echo $row['email'].'<br>'; // echo works okay
            $resultsub =  mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `wp_mm_external_emails` WHERE `email` = '". $row['email'] ."' "); 
            // when I echo this subquery it runs ok. but somehow I get an empty
            while( $rowb = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $resultsub) )
            {
                echo $rowb["email"];
        } else {
            echo "0 $resultsub";
            }
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: what do you get when executing the resultsub query in a db manager (i.e. phpmyadmin)

Comment: i get all when I fill $row['email'] manually. But somehow in this script $resultsub stays empty.

Comment: My ideas are: 
- $resultsub =  mysqli_query($conn is not correct (do not know why not)
- email var is not correct: WHERE `email` = '". $row['email'] ."' ");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you somehow messed your `if-else` and `while` parts up. If I "pretty-print" your code snippet above it looks like this (see my comments):

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM wp_mm_email_bounces");

if ($result) 
{
    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result ) )
    {
        echo $row['email'].'<br>';
        $resultsub =  mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `wp_mm_external_emails` WHERE `email` = '". $row['email'] ."' "); 

        while( $rowb = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $resultsub) )
        {
            echo $rowb["email"];
        } 
        else //Where is the corresponding if?
        {
            echo "0 $resultsub";
        }
    }
} //I added this enclosing bracket to the if-statement

else //If this is the corresponding else of your first if at the beginning, then you never closed it
{
    echo "0 results";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use INNER JOIN query?

See the example below:

```
$sqlString = "SELECT ebounces.email as bouces_email, ext.email as ext_email FROM wp_mm_email_bounces ebouces INNER JOIN wp_mm_external_emails ext ON ebounces.email = ext.email";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlString);

if ($result) {
    // output data of each row
    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result ) )
    {
        echo $row['bouces_email'].'<br>'; 
        echo $row["ext_email"];
    }
} 
else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Ps. Put all columns that you need in the SQL Statement.

My bests

Comment: I test the script with an echo, but need it for a DELETE FROM.
Instead of echo $rowb["email"]; I will need this: $conn->query("DELETE FROM wp_mm_external_emails WHERE email= '".$email."' "); 
To delete all bounced email addresses from the table.

Comment: @Hermants, this sounds like a new question. That does not belong in the comments. If this answer is a correct answer to your question that specified the problem based on `echo` (not `delete from`), then please accept it. You can ask a new question and think about immediately asking what you really need.

Comment: Ok so, try to use a DELETE using Inner Join, like an example below.

    $sqlString = "DELETE s.* FROM wp_mm_external_emails s INNER JOIN wp_mm_email_bounces n ON s.email = n.email";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlString);

My bests

Comment: did not know that it I have to describe so explicit. I will start a new thread.

Comment: Try to use the last example.